# Input box text alignment in IE9 vs IE7/8

Tags: html

I have an input box which is present inside a Div tag.

My issue is when I type some text in this input button, the alignment of the text looks good in IE9. However, when I type text in IE7/IE8 the text gets aligned to the top, not in the center.

How can I fix it?

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is line height issue in different browser so
I am using this method

http://jsfiddle.net/DA3s5/

```
<span>
     <input name="" value="" type="text" />
</span>


span{ border:1px solid red; background:gray;}

span input{ border:none; background:none;}
```